# Content Based Routing in Apache HTTP Server

Tags: apache, http, routes, webserver, load-balancing

I am have a requirement wherein I need to route between two platforms based on the element value of the incoming xml requests. 
If the text for the element is like: `<name>Websphere</name>` then I need to route the message to host1.
If the text for the element is like: `<name>oracle</name>` then I need to route the request to host2.

host1 and host2 are two instances of weblogic application servers. There is a apache http server in front of these two weblogic instances.

The xml element `(<name>)` is in the content of the xml message and not as a part of the URL.

Please advice whow this can be achieved in apache http server.

Thanks.

Comment: this is a question where you'll certainly get more answers on serverfault.com (lot of admins there)

Comment: thx. posted in serverfault.com as well :-)